# Обработка форм в цикле на php

Tags: php, html

Занимаюсь php недавно, и столкнулся с такой проблемой: я пытаюсь обработать формы, которые выводятся в цикле. Я им присваиваю уникальные `name` и `id`, которые зависят от `id` пользователя из бд (использую RedBeanPhp). Но `$_POST`, когда я обращаюсь к формам по `name`, не видит их, соответственно я не могу записать изменения в бд. Возможно, дело в том, что я неправильно записываю атрибуты формы, когда вписываю туда переменную из php?
Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
<?php
   
require_once "../db/db.php"; //файл  с БД

//это обработка форм, кнопку save $_POST видит, а check4, check3 и check2 - нет
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
   $user = R::findAll('users');
   $check4 = $_POST['check4'];
   $check3 = $_POST['check3'];
   $check2 = $_POST['check2'];
   foreach ($user as $item){
      $item->role = 0;
      //если чекбокс выбран
      if ($check4[$item->id] == 'Yes') {
         $item->role += 4;
      }
      if ($check3[$item->id] == 'Yes') {
         $item->role += 3;
      }
      if ($check2[$item->id] == 'Yes') {
         $item->role += 2;
      }
      R::store($item);
   }
}
?>

<html>
<body>
   <form action="users.php" method="post">
       <!-- кнопка, ее $_POST видит -->
       <button class="btn btn-primary" name="save" type="submit">Применить изменения</button>
    </form><br>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Имя</th>
        <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
        <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
        <th scope="col">Логин</th>
        <th scope="col">Права доступа</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    $user = R::findAll('users');
    foreach ($user as $item) {
        //вывод из бд, работает нормально
        echo "<tr><th scope='row'>{$item->id}</th><td>{$item->name}</td><td>{$item->surname}</td>
            <td>{$item->email}</td><td>{$item->login}</td><td>
                <form action='' method='post'>
                    <!-- это чекбокс check4, я хочу получить его состояние через $_POST, но не могу это сделать -->
                    <input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' id='check4[{$item->id}]' name='check4[{$item->id}]'";
        if ($item->role / 3 > 1 or $item->role % 3 == 1): echo "checked";
        endif;
        echo ">
                    <label class='form-check-label' for='check4[{$item->id}]'>Администратор</label><br>                  
                    <!-- чекбоск check3 -->
                    <input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' id='check3[{$item->id}]' name='check3[{$item->id}]'";
        if ($item->role % 2 == 1): echo "checked";
        endif;
        echo ">
                    <label class='form-check-label' for='check3[{$item->id}]'>Преподаватель</label><br>
                    <!-- чекбокс check2 -->
                    <input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' id='check2[{$item->id}]' name='check2[{$item->id}]'";
        if ($item->role / 3 > 1 or $item->role % 3 == 2): echo "checked";
        endif;
        echo ">
                    <label class='form-check-label' for='check2[{$item->id}]'>Студент</label>
                </form>
            </td></tr>                             
        ";
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте отловить сначала все внутренности Post-запроса:

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
  var_dump($_POST);
 ...
```

Comment: Вот такой получился вывод: 'array(1) { ["save"]=> string(0) "" }'
То есть только одна кнопка.
Я попробовал писать имена чекбоксов и без переменной из цикла, в $_POST их все равно нет

Comment: Смотрите, у Вас кнопка save находится вне самой формы - тега <form>. Получается есть два варианта: 1) сделать для каждой формы свою кнопку save; 2) сделать одну большущую форму со всеми полями сразу.

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо огромное!